# Input Error when running WSH script

Tags: input, wsh

I'm trying to run WSH script using cscript specifically
in cmd I got this Error

```
Input Error: There is no script file specified.
```

using this command

```
cscript  c:\file.wsh
```

On windows 7 ultimate
My WSH script simply writes a registry entry
I don't want to use vbscript (.vbs) or wscript engine 
so how can I make my WSH script work ?

Comment: Your file needs a WSF extension, I believe.

Comment: @Bond What is WSF file? I tried your solution but an error raised when executing file.wsf with the same content of file.wsh !

Comment: Scripts should have one of the following extensions: VBS (for VBScript), JS (for JScript), or WSF (for scripts that can contain either, or both). What scripting language are you using? Try giving it a VBS or JS extension depending on which language you're using.

Comment: @Bond thank you
I did it with jscript but seems no difference between jscript and javascript ?!

Comment: JScript is just Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript (popularly known as JavaScript) so you won't see many differences between the two, assuming you're comparing similar versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### .WSH

The **Windows Script Host control file** (`.wsh`) is a text document in which you can customize the execution of one or more of your scripts. It is created automatically when you set the properties for a supported script file.

The following example illustrates a typical `.wsh` file:

```
[ScriptFile]
Path=C:\WINNT\Samples\WSH\showprop.vbs
[Options]
Timeout=0
DisplayLogo=1
BatchMode=0
```

The path information in the `[ScriptFile]` section identifies the script file that is associated with the `.wsh` file. The keys in the `[Options]` section correspond to settings in the *Script* tab within the *Properties* dialog box.

Note:

- You must have the original script file present when executing the `.wsh` file. If the `.wsh` file fails to run the script, **check the `Path=` information in the `.wsh` file** to ensure that it points to the script you are attempting to run.
- When you double-click a `.wsh` file or run it from the command line, `CScript.exe` or `WScript.exe` reads the `.wsh` file to determine the specific settings that should be used to execute the script. `CScript`/`WScript` executes the original script, passing in the properties that are defined within the `.wsh` file.
- It's not possible to specify script parameters with the `.wsh` file. You must run the script (either the script file or the `.wsh` file) from a command prompt to add the parameters.

Resource: [Setting and Customizing Script Properties (.wsh)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8fe3wt9(v=vs.84).aspx)